# Pass LocalStorage Object to Mounted data variable

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I would like to pass LocalStorage Object to mounted data variable. How can I retrieve the values from object and pass into variable. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

```
  mounted() {

  if (localStorage.login.user) {
  this.user= localStorage.login.user;
  }
  if (localStorage.login.email) {
  this.email = JSON.parse(localStorage.login.email);
  }
},
  var login = { user: this.user, email: this.email };
  localStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify(login));
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach you were trying is the correct one. You just need to make sure that the variables `this.user` and `this.email` do exists and have values.

Use the [setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) method to store values, and [getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) to access the values. Values that are stored as stringified objects, they need to be parsed when accessed.

[image]

See also: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/2289769)
 Stackoverflow article.

More information about the localStorage, you can check out the [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) documentation.